# The AJAX form in DjangoCMS

Tags: python, ajax, forms, django-cms

I am trying to build a simple website using DjangoCMS. Now I want to add a contact form, using jQuery AJAX.

I have a few ideas:

1. Use a ready-to-use plugin eg. [Aldryn Forms](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-forms), and just write some AJAX to post my form
2. Create my own app as a Custom Plugin
3. Just create [form_name].py, link up the file in urls.py and push my form to this URL

Which is possible and, if more than one, which is most correct?